# Only call method once when binding attribute in Angular

Tags: html, angular

In the [data] attribute in the object tag, a method is called that returns a link to a PDF, which then the browsers default PODF viewer. The problem that I am encountering is that the PDF viewer keeps flashing because the method keeps getting called and returning the URL. Is there a way I can only fire this method once?

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'pdf'"
       id="pdf"
       class="pdf">

    <object style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
            [data]="returnEncodedLink()"> </object>

  </div>
```

Comment: call this method in your .ts and store response in a variable and pass that variable in this [data] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use getter method and it will be only trigger if its return value changed.
Ts file:

```
encodedLinkData = ''
...
get returnEncodedLink(){
return encodedLinkData
}
```

Html file:

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'pdf'"
       id="pdf"
       class="pdf">

    <object style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
            [data]="returnEncodedLink"> </object>

  </div>
```

Comment: sorry for mistake ..I have edited it to [data]="returnEncodedLink"

Comment: good approach to use getter function, that's a good way to Intercept every change automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Every time change detection fires it will check all variables in your template to see if they have changed.

If you provide a function, change detection will need to call the function in order to see if it returns a different value.

If you only want your function to be called once, then just call it in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, and assign the result to a variable. Then change detection can simply check the identity of this variable rather than calling your function.

**In component ts file**

```js
encodedLink = '';

ngOnInit(){
   this.encodedLink = this.returnEncodedLink();
}
```

**html**

```html
<div *ngSwitchCase="'pdf'" id="pdf" class="pdf">
  <object
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
    [data]="encodedLink"
  ></object>
</div>
```